# Odoo Move field

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-view

I am trying to move a field under res.partner. The field is Barcode and it is under notebook Sales & Purchases. I added a field to the form view but as I have found out Odoo only allows on field per view. Below code works but does not display any data.

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='category_id']" position="after">
                <field name="barcode" />
                <field name="pin"
```

[image]

The barcode field seems to be `point_of_sale.view_partner_property_form`

[image]

I tried below but it did not remove the barcode field

```
<!--Form -->
<odoo>
    <record id="view_partner_pos_form_extend" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.partner.pos.form.view.extend</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="point_of_sale.view_partner_property_form" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='barcode']" position="replace">      
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record> 
</odoo>
```

Comment: Both answers seem correct, could you please edit in all your partner form view extensions?

Answer (score 2):

The `xpath` with a position `after`, `before`, `inside` or `replace` can thus now
have another xpath as **direct** child with position `move`.

The `position='move'` has been introduced to [move](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py#L720) an element in an inherited
view.

It's used as

```
<xpath expr="//@target" position="after">
    <xpath expr="//@node" position="move"/>
</xpath>
```

or also

```
<field name="target_field" position="after">
    <field name="my_field" position="move"/>
</field>
```

Comment: Sorry to wake up such an old post, I was just wondering if there was a possibility to move a field AND all of its attributes (like onchange, invisible, etc...) so you don't have to check every inheritance of that field when you move it.

Comment: Thank you @Kenly for your answer, but I guess this only applies to Odoo v12 right ? Thank you anyway for your pointer, maybe we can implement that manually in our version (v7)

Comment: Why not using `fields view get` to get the field with its attributes and use `position='replace'` then `position='after'` to move the field.

Comment: Very interesting suggestion. I may have an idea on how to do that now, thank you very much @Kenly !